# Video Embed Field: Check All My Videos on existance?

Tags: 8, media

My question on drupal.org did not have an answer:
[To check if YouTube video exists in all my nodes?](https://www.drupal.org/node/2784045)

Please yow to do these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the quickest solution is to query the DB and export all youtube video IDs. 
After you can write a custom PHP script to check if the video exists.
Here is an example of the code you could use: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21069917

A more *Drupalistic* approach is to write a custom module which do the same thing. For example it could implement a drupal cron task or a batch procedure to verify each Youtube field content using the code suggested before.

I hope this suggestion will be helpful.